# TypeError: Cannot call method 'matches' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I am writing a node module that tests an array of words against one word to see if it is an anagram (I know the functionality below for testing that is not correct yet), but I'm running into the error that's described in the title. From what I understand, it means that the object that should contain the method 'matches' is not set, and I'm having trouble understanding how I handle this. Here is the contents of the anagram module:

```
var Anagram = function(a){

    this.word = a;

    this.matches = function(array){

        var found = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

            if(is_anagram(array[i],this.word)) found.push(array[i]);

        }
        return found;
    }
};

function is_anagram(word, check){
    if(word.length == check.length)return true;
    return false;
}

module.exports = Anagram;
```

In my test file (using Jasmine:

```
var anagram = require('./anagram');

describe('Anagram', function() {

  it("no matches",function() {
    var subject = anagram("diaper");
    var matches = subject.matches([ "hello", "world", "zombies", "pants"]);

    expect(matches).toEqual([]);
  });
});
```

I'm still a bit new to js. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your constrains you need to add a 'return this' in the end of the Anagram function:

```
var Anagram = function(a){
    this.word = a;
    this.matches = function(array){
        var found = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(is_anagram(array[i],this.word)) found.push(array[i]);
        }
        return found;
    }
    return this;
};
```

Additionally I would suggest to put your is_anagram function inside of the Anagram.

Comment: Oh, wow! That was easy. What is the reason for having the object need return itself? And what is the reason for putting is_anagram inside?

Comment: If you don't use the function as a constructor, as it's required by your challenge, it just gets executed. So, if no return specified, the undefined will be returned.

Comment: If you put is_anagram inside, you'll have 2 pros: 1. you shouldn't specify 'check' var, it makes your code cleaner. 2. the is_anagram function will be closured so the global scope will be cleaner.

Comment: Since it is being called without a `new`, the `this` in this instance will be the global `window` object. That means these functions will get put on the window. Instead, you shouldn't use `this` at all.

Comment: Not sure if it's crucial for node module. In any case if I was a teacher who gave such task, the next task would probably to change the code to use Anagram as a constructor (`var subject = new anagram("diaper");`). Current approach fits such task too without any code changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var subject = anagram("diaper");
```

should be

```
var subject = new anagram("diaper");
```

You have created a constructor function, but you are using it like a normal function.

For clarity, I'd probably keep the capitalization consistent as well:

```
var Anagram = require('./anagram');
```

with

```
var subject = new Anagram("diaper");
```

#### Edit

Since you can't change the testing code to use `new`, then you should change the structure of your program to create an object instance yourself.

```
function is_anagram(word, check){
  if (word.length == check.length) return true;
  return false;
}

module.exports = function(word){
  // Just return an object with a single 'matches' function
  return {
    matches: function(array){
      var found = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (is_anagram(array[i], word)) found.push(array[i]);
      }
      return found;
    }
  };
};
```

Or perhaps even clearer:

```
module.exports = function(word){
  return {
    matches: function(array){
      return array.filter(function(item){
        return is_anagram(item, word)
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: I see. So it isn't being set up as an object? To clarify, I'm doing this as a coding challenge through exercism.io, and in my case the test file shouldn't be changed. How should the code in the module be structured to fit the test case?